# Matlab: mean and stddev in a cell

Tags: matlab, mean, cell-array

In a single array it's pretty simple to get the `mean` or standard deviation (`std`) of its numbers, however in a cell, whose data doesn't have the same size in each of its positions I couldn't do `mean2` or `std2`.

I know it's possible to do something if I copy all of the data in a single row or single column but I just wanted to ask if someone knows if there is a single formula to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us an example of your data and the expected output?

Comment: you want to compute the `mean` per cell elemets, or the `mean` of all the elements in all the cells? please add a small example that illustrate what you want to achieve

Comment: Hi @Shai, I wanted to get the mean and stddev of all elements in the cell but you already gave the answer. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to compute per-cell `mean` and `std`:

```
cell_mean = cellfun(@mean, my_cell);
cell_std = cellfun(@std, my_cell);
```

For example:

```
>> my_cell = {[1,2,3,6,8], [2,4,20]}
>> cellfun(@mean, my_cell)
ans =

4.0000    8.6667

>> cellfun(@std, my_cell)
ans =

2.9155    9.8658
```

---

If you want the `mean` and/or `std` of all the elements in all the cells, you can:

```
>> mean([my_cell{:}])
ans =

5.7500

>> std([my_cell{:}])
ans =

6.2048
```

And, if your cell elements are all of different sizes, you can use [`cell2mat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) to assist you:

```
>> mean(cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) x(:)', my_cell, 'uni', 0)))
ans =

5.7500

>> std(cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) x(:)', my_cell, 'uni', 0)))
ans =

6.2048
```

Comment: The last paragraph is restricted to row vectors of different lengths. Matrices with different sizes won't work with.